# Speech to Text - Dragon Speaking software alternative

Tags: software-recommendation, speech-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to Dragon Naturally Speaking?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15749/alternative-to-dragon-naturally-speaking)

Is there any good speech to text tool like one we have for Win & Mac named Dragon Speaking software?

I found this question - [Alternative to Dragon Naturally Speaking?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15749/alternative-to-dragon-naturally-speaking) and I was wondering if anyone has tried anything from the list - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition_in_Linux which works good enough.

I am looking for some recommendations on the basis of what has worked for other community members. Can't try all of them one by one.