# Can I dictate to the Linux desktop?

Tags: speech-recognition

Are there any programs that will let me dictate (speech-to-text) to any program? Or at least to a text editor and text fields in Firefox.

I’m not interested in anything that uses an online service, it has to be on-device. It may be a commercial product.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/161515/speech-recognition-app-to-convert-mp3-to-text

Answer (score 2):

I know there're a few programs use on Windows that will accomplish what you mentioned,one that comes to mind is **Dragon Naturally Speaking.** You can read about it here; [Dragon Naturally Speaking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15749/alternative-to-dragon-naturally-speaking)

According to the article you may be able to run **Dragon Naturally Speaking** using Wine for Ubuntu, I use it on Windows many time and it work GREAT. I hope this will point you in the right direction

There are a few others you might want to try I did a search in the Ubuntu Software center and found one called [**Simon**](https://simon.kde.org/) it can be installed on Ubuntu Linux using the Software center

Comment: simon has been deprecated, I believe